# Gradient and Hessian of $x/||x||_2$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, vector-fields, jacobian

I am trying to compute the gradient and the Hessian matrix of the function $f(x):= \frac{x}{||x||_2} $ for $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ where $||x||_2$ is the Euclidean norm. I think that the gradient should be
$\nabla f(x) = \frac{1}{||x||_2^3} (||x||_2^2 Id -x) $ but I have problems in computing the Hessian matrix.

Comment: Note that your function is vector valued. Therefore your "gradient" is a matrix and is usually called the Jacobian.  [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4197252/derivative-of-a-function-divided-by-its-norm-i-e-phix-fracfx-fx) might be helpful.

Comment: Oh thanks! And what about the Hessian?

Comment: Hessians are for scalar fields. You have a vector field.

Comment: $||x||_2^2 Id -x$? What does it mean to subtract a vector from a matrix?

Comment: No, I think the way around. I now realize that I am more interested in $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}$ and $\frac{\partial f^2}{\partial x_i \partial x_j}$

Comment: By $\Vert x\Vert_2$, do you mean $\sqrt{x\cdot x}$ or $x\cdot x$? Either way, $\Vert x\Vert_2^2\operatorname{Id}-x$ is dimensionally inconsistent (not to mention the matrix-minus-vector issue @RodrigodeAzevedo mentioned).

Comment: Work in index notation. Since $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}r^2=2x_i$, $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}g(r)=\frac{g^\prime(r)}{r}x_i$ for scalar $g$, so$$\frac{\partial f_k}{\partial x_i}=\frac{\delta_{ik}-x_ix_k}{r},\,\frac{\partial^2f_k}{\partial x_i\partial x_j}=\frac{3x_ix_jx_k}{r^5}-\frac{\delta_{ik}x_j+\delta_{ij}x_k+\delta_{jk}x_i}{r^3}$$(assuming $\Vert x\Vert_2$ meant the polar radius $r$ rather than $r^2$). You can work this all out with the chain and product rules, and I leave that to you. The results are fully symmetric as $f_k=\frac{\partial r}{\partial x_k}$.

Comment: Shouldn't it be $\frac{\partial f_k}{\partial x_i} = \frac{\delta_{ik} r^2-x_ix_k}{r^3} = \frac{\delta_{ik}}{r}-\frac{x_i x_k}{r^3}$?